How can I create a context for tRPC with the request object in Next.js?
I have a file src/app/api/trpc/[trpc]/route.ts with
const handler = withAxiomRouteHandler((req: NextRequest) =>
// ...
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

This works just fine. The problem is with another file that I have in this project, src/trpc/server.ts.
export const api = createTRPCProxyClient<AppRouter>({

I don't have the request here, I guess?
The issue is that I'm expecting the context to contain the request, because I want to inject axiom in the requests to log application errors.
So, in this boilerplate code:
links: [
    loggerLink({
      enabled: (op) =>
        process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" || (op.direction === "down" && op.result instanceof Error),
    }),
    () => {
      return ({ op }) => {
        return observable((observer) => {
          createContext() //     <------- req?
            .then((ctx) => {
              return callProcedure({
                procedures: appRouter._def.procedures,
                path: op.path,
                rawInput: op.input,
                ctx,
                type: op.type,
              });
            })
            .then((data) => {
              observer.next({ result: { data } });
              observer.complete();
            })
            .catch((cause: TRPCErrorResponse) => {
              observer.error(TRPCClientError.from(cause));
            });
        });
      };
    },
  ],

Could I possibly get the request when creating the context there?
If it's not possible, would it be significantly worse to switch to this?
    unstable_httpBatchStreamLink({
      url: getUrl(),
      headers() {
        return {
          cookie: cookies().toString(),
          "x-trpc-source": "rsc",
        };
      },
    }),

